# renaming *.txt.csv files to .csv in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, export-to-csv

I have .txt files, which I am taking as $item and then I am changing the encoding with

```
iconv -f $currentEncoding -t $targetEncoding "$item" -o "$item.tmp"
```

then I am saving it again to txt file using

```
 mv "$item.tmp" "$item.txt";
```

next I am trimming a few things in txt file and saving it as a csv file with

```
 tr -d '"' < "$item.txt" > "$item.csv";
```

but eventually my files are getting stored with extension "*.txt.csv" - I want them to be just .csv - can anyone help me please what I am doing wrong or what could I change. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
for f in *.txt.csv; do mv $f ${f/.txt./.}; done
```

If the variable `$f` contains the string `item.txt.csv`, the expression `${f/.txt./.}` removes `.txt` from the file name and gives only the string `item.csv`.

Caution: if one of the filenames contain spaces, the `for` statement will not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your $item already has .txt in the value.
So,  if you list your files after each command, you should see intermediate files like

```
xyz.txt.tmp
xyz.txt.txt
xyz.txt.csv
```

So, when you set the item variable, just do ${item%%.*} as shown below and it should work as expected.

```
item=xyz.txt               
item="${item%%.*}"    
echo $item        
xyz
```